# Could I use the PayPal Here web app SDK with Vue Native to create an IOS app that connects to the PayPal Here IOS app?

Tags: vue.js, paypal, vue-native

Seems like a no, but I'm too unfamiliar with Vue Native and PayPal Here to know for sure.

Is there any other way to connect a web app I have to the PayPal Here app on IOS? We are taking payments using the PayPal Here POS, but we also need our web app to know certain items have been purchased.

Answer (score 0):

It *might* be possible to receive [Webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/) for PayPal Here transactions, give it a try.

While not exactly what you are looking for, the [PayPal Here SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/paypal-here/) could be of interest.